# Xamarin Forms CustomPicker issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I did wrote a CustomRenderer on XamarinForms to stylize my Pickers. But on the regular Pickers i encounter the issue now, that if i select them, but tap anywhere on the screen so that they get unfocused without clicking on the prompts turns them unusable. So i can´t Select the same picker again anymore, since the focus (or clicked) Event is not firing anymore. Oddly enough i also have a Date and a Time Picker with the same stylized Content where this Problem doesn´t happen...

XAML For the Picker :

```
<CustomAndroidPicker:CustomAndroidPicker x:Name="ParkPicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" SelectedIndexChanged="ParkSelectionChanged" />
```

And that is the Code i wired up my CustomRenderer on the Android Specific Project :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomAndroidPicker), typeof(CustomPickerAndroid))]
namespace SolarmonAndroidApp.Droid
{
public class CustomPickerAndroid : PickerRenderer
{
    public CustomPickerAndroid(Context context) : base (context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Background = Android.App.Application.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.CustomAndroidEntryDraw);
            Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            Control.SetPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);
        }            
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two PickerRenderer's the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer` and the basic `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` one, the basic one has this issue what you actually need to do is something like:

```
namespace SolarmonAndroidApp.Droid
{
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomAndroidPicker), typeof(CustomPickerAndroid))]
 public class CustomPickerAndroid : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer
 {
    public CustomPickerAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Background = Android.App.Application.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.CustomAndroidEntryDraw);
            Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            Control.SetPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That totally works! And it even looks better (imho) as the Wheel Picker :) Thank you very much, you are my MVP ;)

Comment: Sure no problem at all

Comment: Just wondering, do you know why this happens to the one i used before? It seems like a bit broken to me!

Comment: That one is actually the latest version of the picker, and hence will work in the latest versions of Android properly(In Most cases), Now the AppCompat version is the one which is maintained so that it is compatible even in the lower versions of Android, and hence is usually better maintained for the same reason, Hope i make sense